# How much area can I see on average if I’m hovering over a deformed sphere?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I had asked this question on math.stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958307) but did not receive an answer.

I’m interested in getting some estimates for how much area I can see in average if I’m above (let’s say height $h$) of a surface diffeomorphic to a sphere. By average I mean to get an estimate for some (maybe negative) power of the area averaged over the surface.

Let’s start with a circle of radius $r$. If I’m on a height $h$ (i.e. on a distance of $h+r$ from the center), the horizon is at a distance of $d= \sqrt{2rh + h^2}$ and the length of the perimeter I can see in one direction is $r \arctan (d/r)$ which gives  $x=\sqrt{2rh}$ in lowest order of $h$ .

If I’m on a sphere, the area I can see is $A = \pi x^2 = 2 \pi r h$ in lowest order of $h$.
If I’m on a surface with the two main curvatures $\kappa_{1,2} = 1/r_{1,2}$ the area is in lowest order an ellipse with area $A = 2 \pi \sqrt{r_1 r_2} h$.

We know by Gauss-Bonnet that if we integrate the Gauss curvature $\kappa_{1}\kappa_{2}$ over a surface diffeomorphic to a sphere we get $4\pi$.

Putting this together we can see after elementary algebraic manipulation that in lowest order of $h$ we have 
$$<A^{-2}>^{-1} = \pi h^2 \cdot \textrm{(Surface area of the deformed sphere),}$$ where by $<x>$ I mean the quantity $x$ averaged over the surface.

My question is: Can one go beyond the second order in $h$, i.e. $<A^{-2}>^{-1} =  \pi \cdot \textrm{(Surface area of the deformed sphere)} \cdot  h^2 +  a h^3  + b h^4 + \ldots$.

Which geometric property is contained in $b, c, \ldots$?

I would also be interested in averages of other powers of the area $A$ one can see from one point hovering at a distance $h$ over the surface as a function of $h$ and geometric properties of the surface considered.

I'm not an expert in differential geometry, perhaps the solution is known; the problem and the estimate above came to me by hiking with friends in a nice hilly landscape and wondering what could be said about the average "panoramaness" (if there are points with nice panorama/view, there have to be some with not so nice panorama, can this be made quantitative).